# Select rows by condition without groupby in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have SQL table like below.

| Type | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 |
| 2 | 11111 |
| 1 | 22222 |
| 2 | 22222 |
| 1 | 33333 |
| 2 | 33333 |

And would like to get below result.

| Type_1 | Code_1 | Type_2 | Code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 2 | 11111 |
| 1 | 22222 | 2 | 22222 |
| 1 | 33333 | 2 | 33333 |

Please help.

Comment: What specifically is giving you trouble? Or do you just want somebody to do it for you?

Comment: BTW please tag your question with your DBMS implementation - it helps in giving more relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to perform a self join. AKA, you want to join rows from a table to itself.

Here is a basic example using your sample data that will return what you want, just keep in mind there's always more than one way to do things, and this particular way may not be the most efficient for wherever you plan to copy and use it:

```sql
SELECT s1.Type AS Type_1
    , s1.Code AS Code_1
    , s2.Type AS Type_2
    , s2.Code AS Code_2
FROM Sample s1
    JOIN Sample s2 ON s2.Code = s1.Code AND s2.Type = 2
WHERE s1.Type = 1;
```

Comment: Should be `WHERE s1.Type = 1;`

Comment: @costaparas good catch, thanks. Typed this one on my phone 

Comment: Also, better to use `AS` for the column alias - since we don't know what DBMS the OP is using.

Comment: @costaparas oh that's weird, I didn't even notice. I don't follow the `sql` tag, I only follow the `sql-server` tag. I must have clicked on this from the main feed. I'll fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `self join` as follows:

```
select t1.code, t1.type, t2.code, t2.type
  from your_Table t1 join your_Table t2
    on t1.code = t2.code
 where t1.type = 1 and t2.type = 2
```

I am considering that `type` 1 and 2 records will always be present in the table for each `code`. If no, Then use `FULL OUTER JOIN` with only `JOIN` conditions (conditions from `WHERE` should be moved to `JOIN` condition)