# Filter rows and select in to another columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below.

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End

create table #Temp
(
    Type int, 
    Code Varchar(50),   
)

Insert Into #Temp
SELECT 1,'1'
UNION
SELECT 1,'2'
UNION
SELECT 1,'3'
UNION
SELECT 2,'4'
UNION
SELECT 2,'5'
UNION
SELECT 2,'6'

select * from #Temp
```

And would like to get the below result.

| Type_1 | Code_1 | Type_2 | Code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 6 |

I have tried with union and inner join, but not getting desired result. Please help.

Comment: You are using which database? Please tag it

Comment: Why do you need a query for the desired output and why can't you just setup the output as a table?

Comment: @Popeye : tagged... Thank you...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I have a table with data ( #temp) already.

Comment: @DaleK :   select a.Type as Type_1,a.Code as code_1,b.Type as Type_2,b.Code as code_2 from #Temp a inner join #Temp b 
on a.Type=b.Type where a.Type=1 and b.Type=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select rows by condition without groupby in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246601/select-rows-by-condition-without-groupby-in-sql)

Comment: [edit] and addition info into the quesiton.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin : No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `full outer join` and `cte` as follows:

```
With cte as
(Select type, code,
        Row_number() over (partition by type order by code) as rn
  From your_table t)
Select t1.type, t1.code, t2.type, t2.code
  From cte t1 full join cte t2
    On t1.rn = t2.rn and t1.type =1 and t2.type = 2
```

Comment: FYI, the `FULL JOIN ` isn't necessary. Just move the `t1.type = 1` predicate to the `WHERE` clause and change it to an `INNER JOIN`. I personally try to avoid using `FULL JOIN` unless I have to use it.

Comment: In case there are fewer records in one of the types, the full join will give a proper solution.

Comment: did you try running your code against their sample data? Despite it being marked as the answer, your query does not produce the expected output they asked for. Your query has Types 1 and 2 on the left as well as on the right with NULL records on either side. Based on their provided expected output, they asked only for an inner join with 1s on the left, joined to 2's on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using aggregation:

```
select max(case when type = 1 then type end) as type_1,
       max(case when type = 1 then code end) as code_1,
       max(case when type = 2 then type end) as type_2,
       max(case when type = 2 then code end) as code_2       
from (select type, code,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by code) as seqnum
      from your_table t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

It would be interesting to know which is faster -- a `join` approach or aggregation.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=796cbe0bc5e7cd605b67cbaf44c39850) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't return anything close to their expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query which will produce the output you expect:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.[Type], t.Code
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Type] ORDER BY t.Code)
    FROM #Temp t
)
SELECT Type_1 = t1.[Type], Code_1 = t1.Code
    ,  Type_2 = t2.[Type], Code_2 = t2.Code
FROM cte t1
    JOIN cte t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn AND t2.[Type] = 2
AND t1.[Type] = 1
```

This query is will filter out any Type_1 records which do not have a Type_2 record. This means if there are an uneven number of Type_1 vs Type_2 records, the extra records will get eliminated.

---

Explanation:

Since there is no obvious way to join the two sets of data, because there is no shared key between them, we need to create one.

So we use this query:

```sql
SELECT t.[Type], t.Code
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Type] ORDER BY t.Code)
FROM #Temp t
```

Which assigns a `ROW_NUMBER` to every row...It restarts the numbering for every `Type` value, and it orders the numbering by the `Code`.

So it will produce:

```
| Type | Code | rn | 
|------|------|----| 
| 1    | 1    | 1  | 
| 1    | 2    | 2  | 
| 1    | 3    | 3  | 

| 2    | 4    | 1  | 
| 2    | 5    | 2  | 
| 2    | 6    | 3  |
```

Now you can see that we have assigned a key to each row of Type 1's and Type 2's which we can use for the joining process.

In order for us to re-use this output, we can stick it in a CTE and perform a self join (not an actual type of join, it just means we want to join a table to itself).

That's what this query is doing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cte t1
    JOIN cte t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn AND t2.[Type] = 2
AND t1.[Type] = 1
```

It's saying, "give me a list of all Type 1 records, and then join all Type 2 records to that using the new ROW_NUMBER we've generated".

Note: All of this works based on the assumption that you always want to join the Type 1's and Type 2's based on the order of their Code.